# Group by a predefined set of keys using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've faced the following problem using LINQ. Say I have a collection of numbers in range from one to five: `[1,2,4,5,0,3,1 ...]`. There could be any number of those in that array. What I want is to transform that array into following structure: `[{number:0, count:5},{number:1, count:3}, {number:2, count:0}....]`. If I use `GroupBy` I miss entry for number 2. Is there any elegant and effective way of doing this using LINQ?

Comment: Your sample input does not match your sample output. Also you say number range from one to five, but your sample input has a zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform an outer join between your collection and a "fixed" collection containing numbers 0 to 5 first. Then group that and do the counting.

Comment: Yup, that's it. In LINQ terms, that would be `fixedNumbers.GroupJoin(collection, x => x, x => x, (f, s) => new { Number = f, Count = s.Count() });`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfNumbers = new int[] {1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1,1,1};
 var result =
   from n in arrayOfNumbers
   group n by n into g
   select new { Number = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

 foreach (var item in result)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number {0}: count {1}", item.Number, item.Count));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)            
{
    pairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("number:" + i, arrayOfNums.Select(x => x == i).Count()));
}
```

Where `arrayOfNums` is your array of values between 0 and 5.
The results are stored in a `List<KeyValuePair>>` in the format you want.

You could improve upon this, instead of using the hardcoded `5` in the loop, you could use find the highest value in the array.